# could stl set::insert cause BSOD?

Tags: c++, stl, set

I have written a 'filemon' utility which basically logs file being opened during a period of time. Now I have exact these two functions in my 'filemon' utility:

```
set<wstring> wstrSet;

// callback - get notified by callback filter driver on any file open operation
void CbFltOpenFileN(
                                    CallbackFilter* Sender,
                                    LPWSTR FileName,
                                    ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
                                    WORD FileAttributes,
                                    WORD ShareMode,
                                    DWORD CreateOptions,
                                    WORD CreateDisposition )
 {
      // don't log for directories
      if (FileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
          return;
      }
      wstring wstr = FileName;
      wstr.append(L"\n");
      //wstrSet.insert(wstr); // as soon as I un-comment this line I start getting BSOD in multiple execution of this utility
 }


// Read all paths stored in the set and write them into the log file
void WritePathsToLog() {
    typedef set<wstring>::const_iterator CI;
    printf("\nNo. of files touched ===> %d\n\n", wstrSet.size());
    for (CI iter = wstrSet.begin(); iter != wstrSet.end(); iter++) {
        fputws((*iter).c_str(), logFile);
    }
}
```

Basically what this code does is that 'filemon' utility interacts with callback filter driver and whenever file is touched by any process the driver reports the respective filename to the 'filemon' utility via CbFltOpenFileN function.

Now the issue is that this 'filemon' utility runs fine on win7 x64 machine 4GB machine but as soon as I uncomment the last line in the CbFltOpenFileN function i.e. start inserting the reported filename in the set then I start getting BSOD mostly with BugCheck 0xCC and sometimes with BugCheck 0x50 which basically indicates that "system is trying to access already freed memory"

P.S. on win7 x64 with 8GB RAM I am not seeing any issue at all irrespective of whether last line in the CbFltOpenFileN function is commented or not.

Currently, 'wstrSet' is using default allocator so do I need to use a specific allocator while declaring set wstrSet; if yes can someone tell me how & why?

- Let me share some more information here:

  - I am using VS2010
  - My utility is a 32 bit application targeted for x86 platform
  - The fileystem filter driver I am using is callabck filter driver provided by Eldos corp.
  - Now I am tetsing this utility using a simulator which generates lots of files and then starts the 'filemon' utility, then it touches all those files and at the end stops the 'filemon' utility. This simulator repeates this process 25 times.
  - Now for case where last line is commented I get empty log file created 25 times as I don't insert anything in set but 'filemon' utility also doesn't causes any BSOD
  - But for case where last line is NOT commented I get log file created each time with path enteries as now I am inserting paths in the set but then during first few iteration, say 2nd or 3rd or 6th, itself 'filemon' utility hits this BSOD scenario.

It's hard for me to repro this issue in debug mode as my simulator take cares of the start/stop of 'filemon' utility and i need to run it multiple time to repro the issue.

Hope this added info helps!!!

Thanks and Regards,
Sachin

Comment: Also are you sure that this exact line causes the BSOD, i.e. you have stepped through your program using a debugger and verified it?

Comment: @Kos: lines of code cannot cause BSOD, unless they run in-kernel. Now, if the OP is using flakey drivers (like some not-well tested filesystem driver of RAMFS thingy to work with all that mem...), the OOM condition could make _that_ driver misbehave and throw up over your desktop

Comment: Not something I know about, which is why I'm asking - if this gets called on every file open operation, from any process, how does the wstrSet object get accessed in any of those address spaces?

Comment: Do you happen to call `CbFltOpenFileN` (directly or indirectly) from a static object's constructor? Or is it otherwise called before `main` has started execution?

Comment: No I don't call it from anywhere, it is a callback method that is called by the driver itself. However, my 'filemon' utility has to register itself with the driver and then attach paths with the driver that it wants the driver to monitor for file open operation. Once that is done, driver starts calling `CbFltOpenFileN` method. In other simple words, first main method of my utility gets executed where it tells driver to monitor and report about file being touched on certain path and finally if any file on that path is touched the driver calls `CbFltOpenFileN` function to report about it.

Comment: Can this function be called concurrently (i.e. can it get called again before the previous call returned)? Also, is the callback allowed to allocate memory (which `std::set` definitely does on insert)?

Comment: Yes it is pretty much possible that it gets called concurrently (but I need to verify it from their help regarding what they do about thread safety). I am not sure why allocating memory inside callback would be a problem? Wouldn't that cause issue on very first iteration of simulator running this 'filemon' utility? Also ehy won't it cause issue on 8GB machine (where simulator runs lot more iteration than on 4GB)?

Comment: In the mean time I noticed that `wstring` also does memory allocation but obviously doesn't crash, so that's unlikely to be the cause. But concurrent calls might be the problem: You do absolutely nothing to prevent two concurrent calls to `insert`. Unless your STL implementation makes unusual additional guarantees, it is not safe to have two concurrent calls modifying the same container. And since insert has to mess around with pointers, it wouldn't be a surprise that the code crashes. So if the function can be called concurrently, you have to protect the call to insert with a mutex.

Comment: Synopsis from their documentation:
_These callback functions are always serialized when they are related to the same file. In other words, if there are two write or read operations on the same file, the callback functions are called first for the first operation, then, after the first callback has returned, for the next operation and so on. The calls are performed by the same thread._ @celtschk Do you think in this scenario I still need a mutex? I mean as long as there is no concurrent call happening for two same element it should not be an issue, right?

Comment: @sactiw: Since you are still accessing *the same set* for different files, and you *change* the set, you need a mutex. Note that internally, a set contains a balanced tree, and inserting may trigger a rebalancing of the tree which may affect *all* nodes of a tree, and during that process the tree structure will probably be temporarily invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If you `CbFltOpenFileN` is a callback function, does this means it has asynchron calls? in that case, you might want to protect the global variable (`wstrSet`) with a mutex...